# hive alter table add column fails due to large number of partitions

Tags: hive, hive-metastore, metastore

I have a table that has more than 300k partitions. When I try to add a new colum like below it runs for many hours and then fails. Metastor rds is on mysql and partitions table has more than 5million rows. Has any one encountered this?

`alter table tablea add columns(col1 string) cacade;`

Error message:

```
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.alterTable(Hive.java:638)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.alterTable(DDLTask.java:3590)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:390)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1839)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1526)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1227)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:336)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processReader(CliDriver.java:474)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processFile(CliDriver.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:793)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:77)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_alter_table_with_environment_context(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1689)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.alter_table_with_environment_context(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1673)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.alter_table_with_environmentContext(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:375)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.alter_table_with_environmentContext(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:322)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:173)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.alter_table_with_environmentContext(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a for loop iterating over each partition and executing

`alter table tablea add columns(col1 string)`

This seems to be the safest way to do it.
Considering the number of partitions attempting to execute cascade at table level results in unpredictable behavior not to mention the time it takes for that to complete.